# Não estou conseguindo obter os dados do Json - React Native

Tags: react, react-native

Não estou conseguindo extrair os dados vindos da api.

Aqui eu recebo os dados:

```
  fetch(config.baseURL + '/calendario/situacao_horarios_mes/TESTE/2020/12')
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(resJson => {            
         this.setState({ datas: resJson || []});
     }).catch(e => console.log(e));

     console.log(this.state.datas);
```

Resultado retornado no `console.log()`;

```
Array [
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-01",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-02",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-03",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-04",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-05",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-06",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-07",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-08",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-09",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-10",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-11",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-12",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-13",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-14",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-15",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-16",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-17",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-18",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-19",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-20",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-21",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-22",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-23",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-24",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-25",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-26",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-27",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-28",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-29",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-30",
  },
  Object {
    "dia": "2020-12-31",
  },
]
```

Eu queria que no `this.state.datas` retornasse apenas a data. Exemplo: `2020-12-01` e assim por diante.

No `alert` eu consigo apenas `[object][object]` ou `undefined`.

Comment: Você quer um array só com as datas? Por que não faz um `.map` só retornando as datas?

Comment: Eu consigo usar o .map fora do render?

Comment: Tenta algo do tipo `let apenasDatas = resJson.map(el => el.dia);` e depois `this.setState({ datas: apenasDatas || []});`

Comment: Obtive esse resultado 
   2020-12-01,2020-12-02,2020-12-03,2020-12-04,2020-12-05,2020-12-06,2020-12-07,2020-12-08,2020-12-09,2020-12-10,2020-12-11,2020-12-12,2020-12-13,2020-12-14,2020-12-15,2020-12-16,2020-12-17,2020-12-18,2020-12-19,2020-12-20,2020-12-21,2020-12-22,2020-12-23,2020-12-24,2020-12-25,2020-12-26,2020-12-27,2020-12-28,2020-12-29,2020-12-30,2020-12-31
   Estrai o que eu preciso porem veio tudo em uma string, eu consigo fazer um loop e mostrar os resultados um a um 
   ex:   
   2020-12-01
   2020-12-02
   2020-12-03
   ...

Comment: Deu certo, eu estava com uma conversão para string sem perceber. Muito Obrigado pela Ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido com a ajuda do Cmte Cardeal

Código Final

```
fetch(config.baseURL + '/calendario/situacao_horarios_mes/TESTE/2020/12')
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(resJson => {            
     let apenasDatas = resJson.map(el => el.dia); 
     this.setState({ datas: apenasDatas || []}); 
     }).catch(e => console.log(e));

     console.log(this.state.datas);
```